# prove $(\sup{|f(x)|})^2\geq(\sup{f(x)})^2$

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

prove $(\sup{|f(x)|})^2\geq(\sup{f(x)})^2$.

$|f(x)|\geq f(x)$

$\sup{|f(x)|}\geq\sup{f(x)}$

$(\sup{|f(x)|})^2\geq(\sup{f(x)})^2$ when $\sup{f(x)}\geq0$
...

I don't know how to prove the other half where $\sup{f(x)}<0$.
Any ideas or new approaches?

Comment: @BaronVT, the OP's proof *does* rely on $f(x)\gt0$ to justify maintaining the direction of the inequality when the expressions on each side are squared.

Comment: My previous comment was in reply to a comment that has been removed.  I would remove mine as well, but for some reason I've lost the ability to do so.  (Also, I should have written "$\sup f(x)\gt0$," not just "$f(x)\gt0$.")

Answer (score 1):

For *any* two functions $f$ and $g$, we have

$$\sup f(x)+\sup g(x)\ge\sup(f(x)+g(x))$$

We also have $|f(x)|+f(x)\ge0$ for all $x$.  Therefore

$$\sup|f(x)|+\sup f(x)\ge\sup(|f(x)|+f(x))\ge0$$

Using the inequality $\sup|f(x)|\ge\sup f(x)$, which the OP proved, it follows that

$$(\sup|f(x)|)^2-(\sup f(x))^2=(\sup|f(x)|-\sup f(x))(\sup|f(x)|+\sup f(x))\ge0$$

(Remark:  The OP was rightfully concerned that $a\gt b$ does not automatically imply $a^2\gt b^2$ if $b\lt0$.)

Answer (score 1):

If $\sup f(x)<0$, then $\inf f(x)<0$ too. Moreover $\sup|f(x)|=|\inf f(x)|$. Then…

Answer (score 0):

> Conjecture:
>
> $(\sup|f(x)|)^2 ≥ (\sup f(x))^2$

Proof:
\begin{align}
|f(x)|&\geq f(x) \\
\sup(|f(x)|)&\geq \sup(f(x))\\
(\sup(|f(x)|))^2&\geq (\sup(f(x)))^2 \; \text{when}\; \sup \; (f(x))\geq 0
\end{align}
Second half:
\begin{align}
\sup(|f(x)|)&+\sup(f(x))\geq 0 \\
\sup(|f(x)|)&\geq -\sup(f(x))\\
\sup(f(x)) < 0 &\xrightarrow{} -\sup(f(x))\geq 0\\
(\sup(|f(x)|))^2&\geq (\sup(f(x)))^2 \; \text{when}\;\sup(f(x))<0
\end{align}